# Cartoon movie where a kid travels to another world

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember, from my chilhood (on the early 2000's but I think it can be older), I saw a movie where a child would travel to another world, or maybe he was from there and went to another place, or something like that.

The key things I remember are 3:

1. He had a pet, but not a dog or a cat. And I don't remember it really much, but I would say it could fly or at least levitate.
2. He was wearing a pajamas all the time I believe.
3. He visited a place with a door, a giant one, that was somehow a wall for "the darkness", so it could not enter in the place they were, but at one moment in the movie, that darkness goes through the door and invade them.

I know absolutely nothing more about this movie. Let's see if you can help me on that.

Comment: From the question title alone, I thought it might have been The Phantom Tollbooth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sound like [*Little Nemo: Adventures in Slumberland*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Nemo:_Adventures_in_Slumberland) (1989)

[image: Poster of Little Nemo: Adventures in Slumberland]

I can see a flying animal in the air and he is wearing pajamas in that poster.

From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104740/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> A young boy whose dreams transcend reality is sucked into his own fantasy, which is everything he has dreamed of until he unleashes a century old secret that may not only destroy this perfect dream world but reality itself.

Trailer below:

Comment: Yes. Totally. I remember now the bed flying and the train in the stairs with the old man. I'll accept this as soon as the 6 minutes more needed to accept an answer passes. And I thought it would be no older than 1995, damn.

Comment: Also, this is based on / inspired by a comic strip which started in 1905.